# HTML form which takes the input and has an if function

Tags: javascript, html

I know this is a basic thing but just starting out guys.

So I need to create a form with a set page title, a set main heading, a form input field and enter button. When the enter button is clicked the programme has to inspect the age entered into the input field and display one message if under 17 and another message if 17 or over.

Here is my code - the if function just isn't working - any ideas?

```
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Name of set title</title>
      <script language="javaScript">
        function AgeLimits()
        {
          if(yourage>=17) document.write("You are old enough to drive");
          else document.write("You are too young to drive");
        }
      </script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Name of set question</h1>
    <p>Please enter your age below</p>
    <hr/>
    <form name="Name of set question">
        <p><input type="text"length="3"name="yourage"></p>
        <p><input type="button"value="Enter"onClick="AgeLimits();"></p>
        <hr/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Define "not working". What happens? What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, invalid HTML isn't going to *help*, so make sure you [find the errors in the HTML](http://validator.w3.org) and fix them.

Comment: you need to get yourage value from input and set it to javascript var

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the element to get the value keyed in by the user:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Name of set title</title>
<script language="javascript">
    function AgeLimits()
    {
        var yourage = document.getElementById("yourage").value;

        if (yourage >= 17) 
            alert("You are old enough to drive");
        else 
            alert("You are too young to drive");
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Name of set question</h1>
    <p>Please enter your age below</p>
    <hr />

    <form method="post">
        <p><input type="text" length="3" id="yourage"></p>
        <p><input type="button" value="Enter" onclick="AgeLimits()"></p>
    </form>
    <hr />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a way to get text entered in textfield. The right way is document.getElrmentByName('yourage').value. Since u are checking value of a variable which is not defined your condition always executes else part

Answer (score 0):

The Function should be like this

```
function AgeLimits()
{
    var yourage=document.getElementById("age").value;
    if(yourage>18)
        window.alert("You are eligible to vote");
    else
        window.alert("You are not eligible.Sorry")
}
```

Add a attribute `id="age"` to the text input !